# Default Windows Roboto Alternative

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, windows, windows-10, windows-7

Somewhat similar to [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78542/web-safe-alternative-to-roboto) question, I'm looking for an alternative to Roboto. My office is pretty locked down. I can't install any new fonts either on my machine or firmwide, but I love the look of Roboto. I'm looking for a similar font that's included in the default Windows 7 fonts (defaults [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_7_font_list)) and to the extent there's a different/better fit in default Windows 10 (defaults [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list)). Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Am I missing something? Can you not look at the fonts and determine yourself which you'd prefer?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no exact match for Roboto. So, have a look through the sans serif fonts on the list: Arial, Lucida sans, Franklin Gothic, Segoe UI, MS Sans Serif, Calibri, etc. Choose one you like.  It's pretty hard to know what you would like or what you think would be "better". My powers of telepathy are not what they used to be, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great tool to use is similar fonts from [identifont](http://www.identifont.com/index.html). They analyze several different features of the each font and deliver a quantitative, ranked list of similar fonts.

You can see the list of the 30 most similar fonts for [Roboto](http://www.identifont.com/find?similar=roboto&q=Go) and [Roboto 2014](http://www.identifont.com/list?3%20roboto%202014%200.30%203FQX%201%203GSO%202%2024PD%202%203GSM%202%209JF%204%209YH%204%20HOV%204%2044HQ%204%204UYQ%204%2043LP%204%20EE0%204%204WTF%204%20DBU%204%20O8U%204%20LP2%204%203Q37%204%20LO0%204%202XBS%204%201ZO0%204%20461D%204%204ASH%204%20K9%204%20HJ5%204%203ACQ%204%202RRV%204%201W8P%204%20RX%204%202IQD%204%201MF%204%204WGK%204) on the left in each of these respective lists. Cross checking these against the list of available fonts in Windows 7 and Windows 10, it looks like **Arial** is the closest match. You could also use the [fonts by appearance tool](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html), which will help identify fonts with similar features (of course, not limited to those available in Windows by default).

Answer (score 1):

Arial and ITC Franklin Gothic are the likeliest options.